# AngularJS clean up after promise is rejected

Tags: angularjs

I need to create basic hierarchy by calling a set of $http requests (via ngResource) and need to do cleanup when the any call fails to give the user another try. Let's say, the hierarchy is City -> Street -> Person, where City can have more Streets and Street more Persons.

The main code I'm using looks like this:

```
/* city is object with cityid: {id: cityId} */
function createCity(city) {
    return City.save(null, city).$promise;
}

/* streets is array with objects {id: streetId, city: cityId} */
function createStreets() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< streets.length; i++) {
        promises.push(Street.save(null, streets[i]).$promise);
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
}

/* person is array with objects {id: personId, street: streetId} */
function createPerson() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< person.length; i++) {
        promises.push(Person.save(null, person[i]).$promise);
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
}

/* city is object {id: cityId} */
function removeCity() {
    return City.delete(city).$promise; 
}

/* streets array with objects as for createStreets method */
function removeStreets() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< streets.length; i++) {
        promises.push(Street.delete({id: streets[i].streetId}).$promise);
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
}

/* person array with objects as for createPerson method */
function removePerson() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< person.length; i++) {
        promises.push(Person.delete({id: person[i].personId}).$promise);
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
}

/* should clean the hierarchy in reversed order */
function cleanup() {
    return removePerson()
        .then(removeStreets)
        .then(removeCity);
}

/* main method */
function buildHierarchy() {
    return createCity()
       .then(createStreets)
       .then(createPerson)
       .catch(cleanup);
}

// somewhere in the code
buildHierarchy();
```

I would expect that when an error will be thrown, methods in the cleanup method will be executed in sequence. But in developer console I can see that even if methods seems to be called in correct order, the execution is in wrong - attempt to remove City is before all Person and Streets are removed and this is not allowed.

Does anyone have any idea, how to make sure, that objects are removed in correct order. It seems as if after the catch block the promises chain is not working.

Thanks for any help/ideas.

Michal

Comment: I noticed that except for `removeStreets()` and `removePerson()`, all function call to Person, Street, City have `$promise` attribute and you push/return that. Please confirm this is not a mistake.

Comment: ^ This. They are obviously resources and should return `$promise`.

Comment: That's correct, the ngResource class actions return promise via te $promise. But the $q.all method returns promise, which is resolved when all promises in array are resolved. This is not the issue.

Comment: A note to the exapmle, the buildHierarchy method works great, first is the City created, then Streets and at the end a Person objects. But when any error happens, the cleanup method within the catch block is not working in the order.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the issue is in your remove functions. `removePerson` and `removeStreets` return the `promises` array. In your other functions you return `$q.all(promises)`, which returns a promise.

Comment: They don't return promises array, but one promise created by $q.all() method, which returns a single promise for an array/object of promises, which is resolved when all promises are resolved.

Comment: Right, but you aren't doing that in the remove functions. You're just returning the array.

Comment: Oh, my fault, I made it just in the example, it's correct in my original code. Sorry for the mistake :( I'm going to fix it.

Comment: What about this line? `promises.push(Person.delete({id: person[i].personId});`? In your create functions it's like this `promises.push(Person.save(null, person[i]).$promise);` - you're adding the `$promise` to the array in the creates, but not in the removes. Is it correct in your code as well?

Comment: thanks you for pointing me on this issue, unfortunately it's again wrong just because of the example I wrote to make shorter example. I have methods which return promises, so there was missing the $promise. Anyway, I have reviewed also my original code, and this is not the issue. It seems that in the catch block, the cleanup method and the promises chain is not working - I'm sure it should, just I'm not able to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the notes, I was able to find the issue in my original code. I think it's worth to mention the issue here, because it happened to me more times.

**Important note:** thanks to @Todd Miller comments I fixed the example in the question, even this was not the core of the problem I had.

This is the important part in the example, which works:

```
/* should clean the hierarchy in reversed order */
function cleanup() {
    return removePerson()
        .then(removeStreets)
        .then(removeCity);
}
```

And this is the code I had in my original source, which didn't work:

```
/* should clean the hierarchy in reversed order */
function cleanup() {
    return removePerson()
       .then(removeStreets())
       .then(removeCity());
}
```

Note the parenthesis in .then() block. Autocomplete is very helpful, but sometimes can misguide you.